# stop `inline-block` and then start again

Tags: css

On a page of mine I have two elements (let's name them X and Z) styled with `inline-block`, so they are positioned one next to the other.

Right below them I want to place three elements (let's name them A,B,C), one next to the other again.

When I insert element A with `inline-block`, it goes next to Z.

If I apply `clear:both` to A, then it goes under (so that's good) but if I also apply `inline-block` to A, then A, B and C go right next to X and Z! How can I override this?

```css
.header h1 {
 text-align: center; 
}

.map img{
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.logo img {
 display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.info {
 padding: 5px ;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #c0dfd9
}

.column1 {
 width: 45%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container" id="contact"> <!-- /CONTACT -->
      <div class="map">
        <img src="img/map.jpg" alt="map">
      </div>
      <div class="header">
        <h1 id="contactheader">Contact me</h1>
        <div>  
          <div class="logo column1">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="info column1">  
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><strong>Email:</strong>John@john.com</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><strong>Address:</strong>Plateia Karitsi 25</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span><strong>Telephone:</strong>+30 1654984</p>
          </div>  

        </div>  <!-- /END CONTACT -->

        <br>

        <footer>

        <div id="copyright">&copy;John 2016</div>

        <div id="twitterbutton"><a href="https://twitter.com/aptbs" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @aptbs</a></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/QOTSA/?fref=ts" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>

        </footer>
```

Comment: do you have access to adding more HTML?  You should wrap X&Z in a container and A&B&C in another container then position those two containers above/below eachother (giving those containers `clear:both`) and you can either float block or use inline-block to make the containers mentioned next to eachother

Comment: Hello many thanks, i inserted a,b,c in a new container and it worked like a charm. thank you! thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Line break: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

```css
div {display: inline-block; padding: 8px 12px; background: #ccc; margin: 4px}
```

```html
<div>x</div>
<div>z</div>
<br>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

No need to complicate simple things.

---

Here's your code modified by what I wrote in the comment:

> You need to remove float rules from X and Z. And then you won't even need the `<br>` because they're in separate blocks. Also, make sure A, B and C are inline-blocks as well (they are blocks now).

```css
.header h1 {text-align: center;}

.map img{width: 100%; height: 100%;}

.logo, #twitterbutton, #copyright, .fb-like {display: inline-block;}

.logo img {display: block; margin: auto;}

.info {padding: 5px; display: inline-block; background-color: #c0dfd9}

.column1 {width: 45%;}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="contact"> <!-- /CONTACT -->
      <div class="map">
        <img src="img/map.jpg" alt="map">
      </div>
      <div class="header">
        <h1 id="contactheader">Contact me</h1>
        <div>  
          <div class="logo column1">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="info column1">  
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><strong>Email:</strong>John@john.com</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><strong>Address:</strong>Plateia Karitsi 25</p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span><strong>Telephone:</strong>+30 1654984</p>
          </div>  

        </div>  <!-- /END CONTACT -->

        <footer>

        <div id="copyright">&copy;John 2016</div>

        <div id="twitterbutton"><a href="https://twitter.com/aptbs" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @aptbs</a></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/QOTSA/?fref=ts" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>

        </footer>
```

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your reply. I inserted <br> between X,Ζ and A,B,C elements but it didnt work...

Comment: Hi, you're welcome! How come it didn't work, can you show the code?

Comment: Why don't you post the code in your question? You can make a nice snipper, like I did. Btw. I checked your code and have no idea what elements to look for, nor I see the br tag anywhere.

Comment: i did it. X = logo | Z=info -- A=copyright | B=twitterbutton | C=fb-like . <br> is there

Comment: Ah, I see now. You need to remove float rules from X and Z. And then you won't even need the <br> because they're in separate blocks. Also, make sure A, B and C are inline-blocks as well (they are blocks now).

Comment: Hey Shomz i got a reply that i should place a,b,c in a new container. and it worked! thanks a lot for your replys and your time. I will try your solution as well now

Comment: Yup, that should work. I just updated my answer with the modified version of your original code, so you can see it. You're welcome, glad you got it fixed.